# Closed convex subset of $l^1$ has infinitely many elements of minimal norm

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

I need help with the following:

Closed convex subset $M=\{x \in l^1: \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n=1\}$ of space $l^1$ containes infinitely many elements of minimal norm. Prove this statement.

I wanted to find $\underset{x \in M}{inf ||x||}$, but I only see that
$$||x||=  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n| \geq  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n=1,$$
so inf is $\geq 1$. I don't know how to find inf, but I don't know also what to do with the other part.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What are the simplest elements of $M$ you can think of? Do these have norm 1?

Comment: Maybe (1,0,0,...), (0,1,0..), etc?

Comment: Yes indeed. Now you have inf(||x||, x in M) >= 1 and infinitely many elements in M with a norm of 1. I believe you are done now?

Comment: Yes, yes, I realized immediately. Thanks a lot for your hint, it's so easy, I cannot believe I didn't see it at first :)

Comment: There are much more elements. What about $x\in M$ such that $x_n\ge 0$ ?